# Simple asynchronous web request that does not get lost on activity state change

Tags: android, asynchronous, activity-lifecycle

I'm trying to figure out how to properly do an asynchronous web request on Android in such a way that when the response comes back, it doesn't get lost if the activity got destroyed and recreated from a state change (for example: a screen rotation) while the request was still in process.

The only work-around that I could think of, was offloading the asynchronous work from the `Activity` to the `Application` class (that is, the class referenced from the manifest's `<application />`), and creating a callback in the `Application` the `Activity` subscribes to on `onCreate` and unsubscribes from on `onDestroy`.

his works, but seems like a hack to me. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and make sure to perform web requests in a [background thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading).

If you need more specific help, make sure to post relevant code.